# jpa 2 CriteriaQuery do not discriminate child entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteriaquery

I have an entity which have a relation of one to many with another entity. say

```
1A -> 1.*B
```

i wrote this query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = super.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> select = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> from = select.from(A.class);
Join<A, B> joinB = from.<A, B>join("b");
select.select(from);
select.where( cb.between(joinB.<Date>get("date"), dateA, dateB) );
```

**the problem:** The query is returning all the child entities instead of only those which meets the *between* constrain.

so even if *A* has 3 child *B* and only two meets the criteria, the query always returns 3 *B's*.

checkin the hibernate's generated sql, i can see this.

```
select a from A where a_id = ? and b_date b.date between ? and ?
```

which is fine, all the entities *A* retrieved meets the criteria, but then a second query is thrown to get the *B* entities.

```
select * from b where aid = ?
```

which is wrong because the select should be

```
select * from b where aid = ? and b.date between ? and ?
```

i had this problem once, but my query did't use *CriteriaBuilder*, and it was solved by using *JOIN FETCH*, but with *CriteriaQuery* i have't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was easy (at the end)  i just had to add a cast from **fetch** to **join**, this is the final query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = super.getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> select = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> from = select.from(A.class);
Join<A, B> joinB =   (Join<A, B>)  from.<A, B>fetch("b");//CAST.
select.select(from);
select.where( cb.between(joinB.<Date>get("date"), dateA, dateB) );
```